# How to re-write Jquery function into angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am newbie to Angular 4. Following function is the one we currently using in asp.net project. Its working perfectly. This function is for change the arrow icon of font awesome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
     $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
     $(this).parent().find(".fa-caret-down").removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-up");
     }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
     $(this).parent().find(".fa-caret-up").removeClass("fa-caret-up").addClass("fa-caret-down");
   });
</script>
```

**How to write the above function in angular 4?**

Comment: start from - what is programming language and what is a function

Comment: Its really not best practice to use jquery in an angular application, I would just figure out how to do this with vanilla javascript and then put it in your `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @MaciejSikora Its not like that.. When I try to execute this function its  shows completely different from my current asp.net project..that y I asked and I clearly mentioned that I am completely new to angular 4

Comment: @Ben I got the problem, but next time try to write better title because the orginal one was scary.

Comment: ok noted @MaciejSikora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Step 1: Install jquery

    Run this command

    npm install jquery --save

    than decalre jquery in your Component file at top like below

    import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    declare var $:any;

    than you can use it directly any fuctioin of component file.
    ngOnInit()
    {
 $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
     $(this).parent().find(".fa-caret-down").removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-up");
     }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
     $(this).parent().find(".fa-caret-up").removeClass("fa-caret-up").addClass("fa-caret-down");
   });
    }
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you. Can you plz explain me this line `declare var $:any;` plz.. Why we declare this $  as variable?

Comment: declare jqurey variable automatically take jqurey path from your node module folder no need to import in your component file.. please up vote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per community and official documentation, you should avoid using jQuery with Angular as there are many ways are there in Angular itself to do such tasks. But still if you feel of using jQuery then you can.

Simply add this code in your component's constructor/ngOnInit (Angular's life cycle hook):

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse',  () => {
      $(this).parent().find(".fa-caret-down").removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-up");
        }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', () => {
          $(this).parent().find(".fa-caret-up").removeClass("fa-caret-up").addClass("fa-caret-down");
```

Assuming you installed jQuery (if not installed, use the command `npm i jquery --save`)

Comment: Except that you really, really shouldn't.

Comment: Comments are always welcome instead of downvotes, Now may I know my mistake here?

Comment: I didn't downvote. My point is that you shouldn't use jQuery with Angular, instead you should wrap things in Renderer2 for example to make it Angular safe.

Comment: Yes, even angular's documentation say to avoid JQeury with angular. But as OP need solution so I have provided the same

Comment: Indeed you have. Although I would argue it's also our responsibility to provide a solution that is also correct and which follows the best practices of the used framework :)

Comment: Cool , Strongly agree with your point. But I assume OP must be awared of this so just asking for the solution, anyways I just updated my answer